# Python IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, list, indexing, range, stocks

I'm attempting to get Python to populate the lists with the closing prices of 500 stocks. While the code seems to work fine for just a few stocks, the large amount poses a problem. Python keeps giving me the following error: "`OneClose.append(Data[i][4]) IndexError: list index out of range.`" I'm not sure how to remedy this problem. No matter what I seem to enter in the range field (31 in this instance), the error persists.

```
raw = open('C:\Model\Stocks\list.txt', 'r').read()
stocks = raw.split('\n')

for stock in stocks:
    Data = ystockquote.get_historical_prices(stock, '20120501', '20120716')

# Create empty lists, quick and dirty
    OneClose = [ ]
    OneDate = [ ]

# Populate lists from downloaded data
    for i in range(1, 31):
        OneDate.append(Data[i][0])
        OneClose.append(Data[i][4])
```

`Data` contains:

```
Data = [['Date', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume', 'Adj Clos'], 
        ['2012-07-13', '86.32', '87.83', '86.32', '87.54', '1937700', '87.5'], 
        ['2012-07-13', '86.32', '87.83', '86.32', '87.59', '2599300', '87.5'], 
        ['2012-07-12', '86.60', '86.97', '85.34', '86.41', '4938300', '86.4'], 
        ['2012-07-11', '88.38', '88.76', '87.01', '87.85', '4208600', '87.8'], 
        ['2012-07-10', '89.08', '89.82', '87.96', '88.25', '3356800', '88.2'], 
        ['2012-07-09', '88.86', '89.08', '88.31', '88.96', '2600900', '88.9'], 
        ['2012-07-06', '88.81', '89.38', '88.35', '88.99', '2192900', '88.9'], 
        ['2012-07-05', '89.20', '89.95', '88.86', '89.57', '1924800', '89.5'], 
        ['2012-07-03', '89.11', '89.75', '89.08', '89.70', '1410400', '89.7'], 
        ['2012-07-02', '89.29', '89.69', '88.28', '89.28', '2289700', '89.2'], 
        ['2012-06-29', '88.62', '89.60', '88.35', '89.60', '4629400', '89.6'], 
        ['2012-06-28', '86.36', '87.25', '85.98', '87.16', '3267100', '87.1'], 
        ['2012-06-27', '86.39', '87.60', '86.24', '87.16', '2887800', '87.1'], 
        ['2012-06-26', '85.91', '86.47', '85.29', '86.18', '2389100', '86.1'], 
        ['2012-06-25', '85.87', '86.31', '85.46', '85.85', '2908900', '85.8'], 
        ['2012-06-22', '87.11', '87.14', '86.38', '86.83', '3026000', '86.8'], 
        ['2012-06-21', '88.04', '88.38', '86.62', '86.73', '3722800', '86.7'], 
        ['2012-06-20', '87.93', '88.28', '87.35', '87.54', '3446800', '87.5'], 
        ['2012-06-19', '87.82', '88.17', '87.52', '87.82', '3212500', '87.8'], 
        ['2012-06-18', '87.07', '87.61', '86.67', '87.31', '2950600', '87.3'], 
        ['2012-06-15', '87.57', '87.91', '87.01', '87.44', '4696100', '87.4'], 
        ['2012-06-14', '86.31', '87.23', '86.06', '86.86', '3334900', '86.8'], 
        ['2012-06-13', '86.30', '86.80', '85.72', '86.13', '3370500', '86.1'], 
        ['2012-06-12', '85.67', '86.74', '85.22', '86.73', '2570900', '86.7'], 
        ['2012-06-11', '86.54', '86.54', '85.08', '85.18', '2098200', '85.1'], 
        ['2012-06-08', '85.18', '86.09', '84.99', '86.00', '2146200', '86.0'], 
        ['2012-06-07', '85.59', '86.19', '85.33', '85.50', '3032400', '85.5'], 
        ['2012-06-06', '83.22', '84.64', '83.03', '84.63', '2776300', '84.6'], 
        ['2012-06-05', '82.59', '82.86', '82.25', '82.51', '3268700', '82.5'], 
        ['2012-06-04', '82.79', '82.99', '81.99', '82.62', '2899900', '82.6'], 
        ['2012-06-01', '83.05', '83.98', '82.72', '82.85', '3539200', '82.8'], 
        ['2012-05-31', '84.45', '85.05', '83.87', '84.41', '3683200', '84.4'], 
        ['2012-05-30', '85.06', '85.12', '84.10', '84.45', '2697100', '84.4'], 
        ['2012-05-29', '85.38', '86.00', '85.13', '85.73', '2142200', '85.7'], 
        ['2012-05-25', '84.87', '85.20', '84.40', '84.78', '2346000', '84.7'], 
        ['2012-05-24', '84.96', '85.00', '84.03', '84.98', '2322100', '84.9'], 
        ['2012-05-23', '83.37', '84.88', '82.95', '84.80', '3200000', '84.8'], 
        ['2012-05-22', '84.69', '84.99', '83.68', '84.13', '3000900', '84.1'],
        ['2012-05-21', '83.88', '84.63', '83.75', '84.46', '2450000', '84.4'],
        ['2012-05-18', '84.78', '84.78', '83.27', '83.51', '3602900', '83.5'],
        ['2012-05-17', '85.56', '85.64', '84.25', '84.34', '2777200', '84.3'],
        ['2012-05-16', '85.91', '86.27', '85.26', '85.35', '2770600', '85.3'],
        ['2012-05-15', '85.95', '86.46', '85.50', '85.78', '2611300', '85.1'],
        ['2012-05-14', '85.46', '86.55', '85.24', '85.83', '2631900', '85.2'],
        ['2012-05-11', '86.47', '87.48', '86.24', '86.73', '2601800', '86.1'],
        ['2012-05-10', '87.14', '87.69', '86.88', '87.13', '2828500', '86.5'],
        ['2012-05-09', '86.64', '87.84', '85.98', '87.27', '3192800', '86.6'],
        ['2012-05-08', '87.12', '87.88', '86.30', '87.56', '2710400', '86.9'],
        ['2012-05-07', '87.70', '88.62', '87.70', '88.01', '2753500', '87.4'],
        ['2012-05-04', '89.17', '89.24', '88.30', '88.67', '2823800', '88.0'],
        ['2012-05-03', '89.50', '89.85', '89.11', '89.39', '2343600', '88.7'],
        ['2012-05-02', '89.16', '89.59', '88.89', '89.52', '2100200', '88.9'],
        ['2012-05-01', '89.13', '89.95', '88.74', '89.60', '2294200', '88.9']
      ]
```

Comment: this Data does not show any error! does it? The error might be in a different set of Data (from a different iteration of "for stock in stocks:")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace:

```
for i in range(1, 31):
```

with:

```
for d in Data[1:31]: #since you have range(1,31). Do Data[1:] if you just want to skip the first
    OneDate.append(d[0])
    OneClose.append(d[4])
```

This usually happends when `Data` array has less than 31 indices. Also ensure `d` array has atleast 5 items, else `d[4]` will also throw a similar error. Use:

```
if len(d) >= 5:  #check first.
    OneDate.append(d[0])
    OneClose.append(d[4])
```

Comment: this might not work as you can see OP is starting the indexes from `1` not from `0`, see `range(1,31)`

Comment: ystockquote is a module that requires the [0] and [4] as references for what data to retrieve from yahoo finance (dates and closing prices respectively). For some reason the above won't work in this instance.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: I edited that out. But OP is still unclear with his question.

Comment: @user1526586 can you post the content of `data` in your post?

Comment: @user1526586: Please edit your question and put in `Data`'s value.

Comment: No, I can't really post this as it's a module that requires the lower portion to actually view.

Comment: @user1526586 you should post the content of `data` in your post, that will make the problem much more clear.

Comment: Basically, I am getting closing prices for several stocks, but not all since the program ends early.

Comment: @user1526586 if you've changed your loop to `for d in Data[1:]`, then `d[4]` can only raise an `IndexError` if `d` is shorter than 5 elements. Doing `print Data`, or catching the `IndexError` and doing `print d` will almost certainly tell you that it doesn't contain what you expect.

Comment: @user1526586 you can check for which stock the program throws the error, try `print stock` and also `print data`.

Comment: it is still useful in 2021 :)

Answer (score -1):

Two things can occur with `Data[i][4]`:

- The list `Data` does not have an element at position `i`.
- The list `Data[i]` does not have an element at position `4`.

Python will raise an `IndexError` in these two situations. Have you checked that your data is valid and that the above situations won't occur?

It could be that data is missing in your text file and that `ystockquote.get_historical_prices` is unable to create a list with the data in the expected format.

Answer (score -1):

One of the elements of `Data` has less than 5 items.

Your code has

```
OneDate.append(Data[i][0])
OneClose.append(Data[i][4])
```

and, the exception is in the second line. So, you can be sure that there definitely is an element in `Data`, at position `i`.  (because, if not present, the exception would have been at the first line itself).

So, the error is because `Data[i]` does not have 5 elements. 
(eg. if Data[i] is a string, it has less than 5 characters in it).

You solution could be to check the length of `Data[i]` and making sure that it has enough elements, before trying to read them.

Answer (score -2):

this error happens when code trigger and exchange data updation at same time. in other terms when data updates fresh every quotes at exactly 5, 10 or 60 mins close bar, there will be milli seconds gap in real time update, so list will be empty in that milli seconds time frame. and this error happens due to that.

Comment: Man WTF are you talking about?