# How can I move the elements in my list without getting an error?

Tags: python, list, element

I get an "Out of range error" everytime I run this code. I'm trying to get the value of i = 0 to i = 2 etc.

```
element = [x for x in range(10)]
l = len(element)
print(element)
for i in range(l):
   element[i] = element[i+1]
print(element)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python IndexError: list index out of range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11500539/python-indexerror-list-index-out-of-range)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend starting with changing `for i in range(l)` to `for i in range(l-1)`. That will ensure that the index `i+1` is less than `l`.

The catch with this is that the last element of `element` won't be changed, but figuring out what to do with that element is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly, your expected result is to change `element` from:

> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

to:

> [0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ]

First, your loop goes one item too far - the last value of i will be the index of the last element; so that `element[i+1]` does not exist. This is easy to fix:

```
for i in range(l-1):
```

but then there is another problem: `element[i] = element[i+1]` moves `element[1]` to `element[0]` etc., so the direction is wrong - what you want is:

```
    element[i+1] = element[i]
```

And anyway, it is much easier and more efficient just to duplicate the first element:

```
element.insert(0, element[0])
```

and remove the last one:

```
element.pop()
```

If I misunderstood and your expected result is in fact:

> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

then

```
element.pop(0)
```

is even simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to copy the last value to an index that doesn't exist yet.You have to use append for the last value.

```
element = [x for x in range(10)]
for i in range(len(element)):
    if i == len(element):
        element.append(element[i])
    else:
        element[i] = element[i+1]
```